# What language is this color code?

Tags: css

I have this code for a color,`0x7FBB00FF`  I don't know how are called this colors with 0x and where I can found a convert for photoshop ?

Comment: hexadecimal colour codes

Comment: Could it be [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's RGBA: hexadecimal with an alpha value at the end - `FF`.

Type the relevant bit of the color code into Google to see it as a hex color (`#7FBB00`): https://www.google.com/search?q=%237FBB00

Comment: Thank You! Best answer ever.

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal.

For #0x = See that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x)

7F = Red

BB = Green

00 = Blue

FF = Alpha

Answer (score 0):

The `0x` prefix usually means hexadecimal.

And each color channel usually uses 1 byte, that is, it ranges between 00 and FF. That's 2 digits in hexadecimal.

The convention order is red (R), green (G), blue (B).

Sometimes an alpha (A) component with the transparency is also added.

So your color is probably in RRGGBBAA.

- Red: 127
- Green: 187
- Blue: 0
- Alpha: 255

In CSS, you would use

```css
rgba(127, 187, 0, 255)
```

Or, since FF usually means fully opaque, you don't need the alpha channel.

```css
rgb(127, 187, 0)
#7FBB00
```

But sometimes the transparency goes to the beginning like AARRGGBB, so you color coulor also be

- Alpha: 127
- Red: 187
- Green: 0
- Blue: 255

Answer (score 0):

That comes from google:

It could be a [Android color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788858/how-to-convert-android-color-format)

or [Q-Image Format](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/gui/QImage.Format.html)

How to easy [convert per Hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203394/convert-rrggbb-hex-value-to-aarrggbb)